# Error displayed after adding link to sidebar in laravel

Tags: laravel

I was trying to add links to sidebar in laravel but I was getting this error message:

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
3/3 ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route [stock-create] not defined. (View: C:\wamp\www\pump\core\resources\views\layouts\dashboard.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp\www\pump\core\resources\views\layouts\dashboard.blade.php)

```
in UrlGenerator.php line 314
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\wamp\www\pump\core\storage\framework\views/d039c120d96bd9a07957a999c1ef8ecb9005ec81.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'page_title' => 'Dashboard', 'site_title' => 'Petrol Pump', 'total_customer' => '22', 'total_machine' => '4', 'total_fuel' => '3', 'total_seller' => '2')) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\wamp\www\pump\core\resources\views/dashboard/dashboard.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'page_title' => 'Dashboard', 'site_title' => 'Petrol Pump', 'total_customer' => '22', 'total_machine' => '4', 'total_fuel' => '3', 'total_seller' => '2')) in View.php line 149
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 53
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 201
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1085
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 95
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 28
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure), 'admin')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Authenticate), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure), 'admin')) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(DashboardController), object(Route), object(Request), 'getDashboard') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController', 'getDashboard') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

2/3 ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route [stock-create] not defined. (View: C:\wamp\www\pump\core\resources\views\layouts\dashboard.blade.php)

```
in UrlGenerator.php line 314
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(InvalidArgumentException), '2') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\wamp\www\pump\core\storage\framework\views/0a6cb83dc869c8b58a8e29ab495dcca8c5afa94f.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'obLevel' => '1', 'page_title' => 'Dashboard', 'site_title' => 'Petrol Pump', 'total_customer' => '22', 'total_machine' => '4', 'total_fuel' => '3', 'total_seller' => '2')) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\wamp\www\pump\core\resources\views/layouts/dashboard.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'obLevel' => '1', 'page_title' => 'Dashboard', 'site_title' => 'Petrol Pump', 'total_customer' => '22', 'total_machine' => '4', 'total_fuel' => '3', 'total_seller' => '2')) in View.php line 149
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in d039c120d96bd9a07957a999c1ef8ecb9005ec81.php line 69
at include('C:\wamp\www\pump\core\storage\framework\views\d039c120d96bd9a07957a999c1ef8ecb9005ec81.php') in PhpEngine.php line 42
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\wamp\www\pump\core\storage\framework\views/d039c120d96bd9a07957a999c1ef8ecb9005ec81.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'page_title' => 'Dashboard', 'site_title' => 'Petrol Pump', 'total_customer' => '22', 'total_machine' => '4', 'total_fuel' => '3', 'total_seller' => '2')) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\wamp\www\pump\core\resources\views/dashboard/dashboard.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'page_title' => 'Dashboard', 'site_title' => 'Petrol Pump', 'total_customer' => '22', 'total_machine' => '4', 'total_fuel' => '3', 'total_seller' => '2')) in View.php line 149
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 53
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 201
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1085
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 95
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 28
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure), 'admin')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Authenticate), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure), 'admin')) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(DashboardController), object(Route), object(Request), 'getDashboard') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController', 'getDashboard') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

1/3 InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route [stock-create] not defined.

```
in UrlGenerator.php line 314
at UrlGenerator->route('stock-create', array(), true) in helpers.php line 616
at route('stock-create') in 0a6cb83dc869c8b58a8e29ab495dcca8c5afa94f.php line 141
at include('C:\wamp\www\pump\core\storage\framework\views\0a6cb83dc869c8b58a8e29ab495dcca8c5afa94f.php') in PhpEngine.php line 42
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\wamp\www\pump\core\storage\framework\views/0a6cb83dc869c8b58a8e29ab495dcca8c5afa94f.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'obLevel' => '1', 'page_title' => 'Dashboard', 'site_title' => 'Petrol Pump', 'total_customer' => '22', 'total_machine' => '4', 'total_fuel' => '3', 'total_seller' => '2')) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\wamp\www\pump\core\resources\views/layouts/dashboard.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'obLevel' => '1', 'page_title' => 'Dashboard', 'site_title' => 'Petrol Pump', 'total_customer' => '22', 'total_machine' => '4', 'total_fuel' => '3', 'total_seller' => '2')) in View.php line 149
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in d039c120d96bd9a07957a999c1ef8ecb9005ec81.php line 69
at include('C:\wamp\www\pump\core\storage\framework\views\d039c120d96bd9a07957a999c1ef8ecb9005ec81.php') in PhpEngine.php line 42
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\wamp\www\pump\core\storage\framework\views/d039c120d96bd9a07957a999c1ef8ecb9005ec81.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'page_title' => 'Dashboard', 'site_title' => 'Petrol Pump', 'total_customer' => '22', 'total_machine' => '4', 'total_fuel' => '3', 'total_seller' => '2')) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\wamp\www\pump\core\resources\views/dashboard/dashboard.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'page_title' => 'Dashboard', 'site_title' => 'Petrol Pump', 'total_customer' => '22', 'total_machine' => '4', 'total_fuel' => '3', 'total_seller' => '2')) in View.php line 149
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 53
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 201
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1085
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 95
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 28
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure), 'admin')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Authenticate), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure), 'admin')) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(DashboardController), object(Route), object(Request), 'getDashboard') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController', 'getDashboard') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

This is my first time of using Laravel, could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: We need to see some code...

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Comment: post your view code and web.php code

Comment: Post your `dashboard.blade.php` and `web.php` files codes here.

Comment: The problem is clear, is that you don't have the route "stock-create" in your routes file. But we asked you to post web.php file and not the error ...

Comment: @HirenGohel, please in which of the folders can I find web.php because i have searched under view and couldn't find it.

Comment: It is not in view, It is in routes folder

Comment: @TonyeBoro It's `routes/web.php`. Check `routes` folder!

Answer (score 0):

It's highly probable that your route is :

```
stock.create
```

and not

```
stock-create
```